# Android Expansion APK Exception on Download Library

Tags: android

I'm following the steps in the dev guide to implement the Google Marketplace (Play) Expansion files setup:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

I'm at the section "Preparing to use the Downloader Library" where I've added the License Lib, Downloader lib and zip lib projects to eclipse and then as libs to my main project. When I running my project, it always throw the exception as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): FATAL EXCEPTION: background thread
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): Process: com.expandinghorizons, PID: 3758
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID    #0x7f040007
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:330)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:346)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at  
 com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadNotification.onDownloadStateChanged
  (DownloadNotification.java:133)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at  
  com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloaderService$LVLRunnable$1.allow 
  (DownloaderService.java:837)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.handleResponse
 (LicenseValidator.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.verify
 (LicenseValidator.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at
   com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker$ResultListener$2.run
  (LicenseChecker.java:228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3758): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Seems the exception is happened on the Google Download libs, how can I do with it? Any one has advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. You need to run the SDK Manager as administrator.